# Problem with padding in series of <a> tag elements

Tags: html, css

I am using a tag for my menu on my website. The following code is for the menu (don't mind the php stuff, it is just there for finding correct relativ path and selecting correct class):

```
<div id="menu">
            <a class="<?php echo $opis; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>">
                Opis
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $novosti; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>">
                Novosti
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $slikeVP; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/slikeVP">
                Slike VP &amp; reportaže
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $podatki; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/podatki">
                Trenutni podatki
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $arhiv; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/arhiv">
                Arhiv
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $zanimiviDogodki; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/arhiv">
                Zanimivi dogodki
            </a>
            <a class="<?php echo $povezave; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/povezave">
                Povezave
            </a>
        </div>
```

And the CSS (I am giving only the not selected, others are almost similar with diffrent background colors.):

```
.notSelected {
border-left: 8px solid #1958b7;
border-right: 8px solid #1958b7;
background-color: #2175bc;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 1px 9px 5px 9px;
```

}

Now problem is with the left and right padding, which is set to 9px. I noticed that the first `<a>Opis</a>` to the second last `<a>Zanimivi dogodki</a>` all have bigger right padding, then 9px. Where the last element `<a>Povezave</a>`, has 9px, which is right. Then I tested with padding left and right 0px, and there was still some space on the right side after all elements except for the last (Povezave). It seems that for some reason they all get spacing after the text, except for the last element. Now I would like to know why is that, and what is the solution to this.

Comment: can you please give us a generic actual output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is coulb be because of the whitespace between the closing and opening of `a` tags.

```
<div id="menu">
        <a class="<?php echo $opis; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>">
            Opis
        </a><a class="<?php echo $novosti; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>">
            Novosti
        </a><a class="<?php echo $slikeVP; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/slikeVP">
            Slike VP &amp; reportaže
        </a><a class="<?php echo $podatki; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/podatki">
            Trenutni podatki
        </a><a class="<?php echo $arhiv; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/arhiv">
            Arhiv
        </a><a class="<?php echo $zanimiviDogodki; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/arhiv">
            Zanimivi dogodki
        </a><a class="<?php echo $povezave; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>/povezave">
            Povezave
        </a>
    </div>
```

should correct it.

You know you wave borders left and right as well, right ?

---

turns out it is the whitespace in the inside of the `<a>` tags, before and after the actual text.

Comment: No, as I have written I tried with padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px, but there is still some space after text (this space is inside <a> tag, because I checked with temporary border.). Ofcourse as I have also written, this for some reason does not apply for last text in <a> tag (Povezave).

Comment: Yeah the border on both left and right side is intentionally. Thanks for your answer it was almost ok, because I had to throw the opening and the closing tag of <a> in one line:<a class="<?php echo $opis; ?>" href="<?php echo $pot; ?>">Opis</a>

Answer (score 0):

Check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/U2h5a/

Looks like you want this to be rendered.